# Dynamics 8.2 RetrieveMultipleAsync Received Message Size Error on only 38 Records

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

Microsoft Dynamics 8.2
I've developed a Fetch Query that returns 38 records in the FetchXML Builder, it works perfectly. When I take the Fetch Query and use it as a FetchExpression in C#, I get a **maxReceivedMessageSize** error on **incoming messages** (server side issue?).

I paired down the query's complexity to only four columns (1 Text, 2 OptionSetValue, 1 UID), FAIL... always with the **maxReceivedMessageSize** error.

I'm using an instance of iOrganizationService that supports my other report perfectly.

Should I use a different QueryBase object?
Should I use RetrieveMultiple instead of RetrieveMultipleAsync?

Comment: Any followup questions?

Answer (score 0):

`RetrieveMultipleAsync` is part of `OrganizationServiceClient` and it is no more supported since the `XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc` is [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2016/developers-guide/dn281891(v=crm.8)).

Better to switch your code to use `IOrganizationService.RetrieveMultiple` and your fetchxml will work along with `FetchExpression`. [Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.xrm.sdk.iorganizationservice.retrievemultiple?view=dynamics-general-ce-9)